# Perl: basic perl regex parsing for word@word

Tags: regex, perl

I get an input to my script (from another script) in this format 
xyz@abc

I have this matching condition in my script

```
 if ($test =~ /.* by (\w+)\@(\w).*/) { print $1; }
```

This one does not have a match for some reason.

I tried this one command line:

option 1:

```
perl -e 'my $aa = "abcd@abcd" ; if ($kk =~ /(\w+)\@(\w+)/) {print "\n  $1 \n $2 \n";}
```

option 2:

```
perl -e 'my $aa = q[abcd@abcd] ; if ($kk =~ /(\w+)@(\w+)/) {print "\n  $1 \n $2 \n";}
```

option 2 prints but not option 1. Could someone pls explain the reasoning.

Comment: Neither of your one-liners actually runs, can you post the actual code you're trying to debug?

Comment: Please don't remove the error you're asking about from the question! Reverted the edit

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in the command line:

You assign variable $aa but do pattern matching on variable $kk.

The second is that @abcd is being interpreted as a variable in the string delimited by "...". The variable @abcd is not defined, so it interpolates to an empty string, and in effect you have $aa = "abcd".

You can see the problem with @ when you type this:

```
perl -e 'my $aa = "abcd@abcd"; print "$aa\n"'
```

You have to mask the @. So try this instead:

```
perl -e 'my $aa = "abcd\@abcd"; if ($aa =~ /(\w+)@(\w+)/ ) {print "\n $1 \n $2 \n";}'
```

Comment: Thanks. The variable name was my mistake. I see your point. How do I make sure in $test (which i get from another script) @ is treated as @ and not an array

Comment: @user8709996 Variables are only interpolated like this when you define the string in your script with double quotes or qq, it wouldn't occur if you read it from somewhere else.

Comment: This is only a problem for literal strings in double quotes. When you have the varibale $test assigned with the correct value, you need not mask the @ in the variable's value.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Appreciate your response.